# How to change layout in fragment using button click C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I'm new on android development, i want to ask a question about changing layout on fragment using button click. When i'm trying to return view on button
it said

Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value

Button seems to be working fine because toast text pop up when i click the button (without return value). Here is my code

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater p0, ViewGroup p1, Bundle p2)
{
            AppPreferences ap = new AppPreferences(mContext);
            var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Kategori, p1, false);
            Button btnTIM= rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnTIM);
            Button btnManShoes= rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnManShoes);

           btnTIM.Click += delegate
           {
                        var myActivity = (MenuUtama)this.Activity;
                        AndHUD.Shared.Show(myActivity, "Loading..");
                        if (myActivity.isOnline() == true)
                            ambilTanggalTIM(ap);
                        else
                            myActivity.internetDropDialog();
            };

        btnManShoes.Click += delegate
        {
                //on this button, i want to change the view to Resource.Layout.ManShoes
                          Toast.MakeText(mContext, "Clicked!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                           rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ManShoes, p1, false);
                           return rootView;  //Got error when return the View
         };

        return rootView;
    }
```

I'm, using Visual Studio 2015 + Xamarin, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer why it doesn't work, [here the link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/209087#Comment_209087)

> You cannot replace the fragment's layout once it is set. If you need
>   conditional layout then you either have to redesign your layout and
>   split it into even smaller fragments, or you could group all layout
>   elements in sub containers (like LinearLayout), then put them all in
>   RelativeLayout, position to overlap each other and swap visibility of
>   these LinearLayoutswith setVisibility()when needed.

You can see my code, but it is in different way. I'm not sure if this is the best way. Here is my code :

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater p0, ViewGroup p1, Bundle p2)
    {
       AppPreferences ap = new AppPreferences(mContext);
       var i = Arguments.GetInt(ArgPlanetNumber);
       if (i == 0)
       {
         var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Kategori, p1, false);
         Button btnTIM= rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnTIM);
         Button btnManShoes= rootView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnManShoes);

         btnTIM.Click += delegate
         {
            var myActivity = (MenuUtama)this.Activity;
            AndHUD.Shared.Show(myActivity, "Loading..");
            if (myActivity.isOnline() == true)
            ambilTanggalTIM(ap);
            else
            myActivity.internetDropDialog();
                };

            btnManShoes.Click += delegate
            {
              var fragment = new PlanetFragment();
              var arguments = new Bundle();

              arguments.PutInt(PlanetFragment.ArgPlanetNumber, 100);
              fragment.Arguments = arguments;

              FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
              .Replace(Resource.Id.content_frame, fragment)
              .Commit();
            };
        }
       else if(i == 10)
       {
         var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Example, p1, false);
         return rootView;
       }
       else if(i == 100)
       {
         var rootView = p0.Inflate(Resource.Layout.ManShoes, p1, false);
         return rootView;
       }

      return rootView;
    }
```

So you can assign the "i" variable and the rootView with whatever you want

Comment: This may not be the most elegant answer, but it worked for me.  Thank you!  I tried to .Replace() the fragment and kept getting exceptions.  I get the LinearLayout using 
            _appSettingsLayout = _view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.appSettingsMainLayout) then just set _appSettingsLayout.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone and vice versa using ViewStates.Visible on the other LinearLayout.